# Redirect after profile update, language specific

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, user-profile

The profile-update URLs for User Profiles are language specific: `.../nl/profile.php` and `.../en/profile.php`. When users click "Update Profile" I can redirect them to any URL. But now I want to test the current URL to see if there's `/nl/` in there, so I can give them a redirect to their own language. I use the code below but the result of the 'if statement' is always `false`. I can see that: when I enter another url there, it picks up that one. So the code seems to work, just the test fails. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'custom_profile_redirect', 12 );
function custom_profile_redirect() {
   if(strpos("//{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}", '/nl/') === false ) {
        wp_redirect( trailingslashit( home_url() . '/en' ) );
    } else { 
        wp_redirect( trailingslashit( home_url() . '/nl' ) );
    } 
    exit;
}
```

[edit:] Variables I managed to retrieve are all set to 'en' after the profile update, even the plugin's global variable. I now worked around it by adding a LanguagePreference dropdown in the sign up form. In the After-Update-Redirect, I read the usermeta and redirect to their own preference. 
There must be better ways to achieve this...

Comment: Hmm... Where is your test?

Comment: Edit your post and add the test like @Bono said so that we can help you.

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant with the test the "if" statement. It always returns false. It's a Wordpress site with the Transposh translation plugin. The plugin adds the /nl/ after the base URL.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers and sorry that I wasn't clear. In the meantime I found out that the REQUEST_URI doesn't include the 'nl/' part although it is displayed in the address bar. So much for that plan. I tried HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE but that's always set to the same language (nl in my case), even when another language is chosen in the site interface. Aaargh! I guess I'll have to look for other variables.